# conditions when the Transaction logs are flushed into the Log File

Tags: sql-server

In which conditions the T-logs are flushed from the log cache to log file or disk?

Does it happen after every commit or after every 3 seconds or only after checkpoint?

And in where the dirty pages are stored in the SQL server when the memory is not big enough to hold the data in the buffer pool(in temp db or in the respective databases)? and for how long the uncommitted data is preserved in SQL server and where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Checkpoint** is an internal process that writes all dirty pages (modified pages) from Buffer Cache to Physical disk, apart from this it also writes the log records from log buffer to physical file.

A checkpoint always writes out all pages that have changed (known as being marked dirty) since the last checkpoint, or since the page was read in from disk. It doesn't matter whether the transaction that changed a page has committed or not – the page is written to disk regardless. The only exception is for tempdb, where data pages are not written to disk as part of a checkpoint.

A checkpoint is only done for tempdb when the tempdb log file reaches 70% full – this is to prevent the tempdb log from growing if at all possible (note that a long-running transaction can still essentially hold the log hostage and prevent it from clearing, just like in a user database).

> Conditions when the Transaction logs are flushed into the Log File:

The LOGWRITER is the process which is responsible for writing logs from Log Cache to Log file.

**The conditions where the log buffer is flushed to disk includes:**

1. A session issues a commit or a rollback command.
2. The log buffer becomes 1/3 full.
3. After every checkpoint.
4. Whenever Log file becomes 70% Full.
5. It also depends on the [Target Recovery Time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/logs/database-checkpoints-sql-server)

> Does it happen after every commit or after every 3 seconds or only
>   after checkpoint?

It happens after every commit and after every checkpoint.

Checkpoint occurs for a user database, all dirty pages for that database are flushed to disk (as well as other operations). This does not happen for tempdb. Tempdb is not recovered in the event of a crash, and so there is no need to force dirty tempdb pages to disk, except in the case where the lazywriter process (part of the buffer pool) has to make space for pages from other databases. When you issue a **manual** CHECKPOINT, all the dirty pages are flushed, but for automatic checkpoints they’re not.

[Checkpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/logs/database-checkpoints-sql-server)

> How long the uncommitted data is preserved in SQL server and where?

SQL Server will keep the uncommitted data in the data and log files unless and until the transaction is completed / rolled back.

Comment: I think asking a question and rewriting your answer after getting all clarifications doesn't give good impressions

Answer (score 0):

You are asking two random questions

1.Transaction log buffer
2.Buffer pool

> In which conditions the T-logs are flushed from the log cache to log file or disk?Does it happen after every commit or after every 3 seconds or only after checkpoint?

Consider below update statement

```
Update table set id=1
where id=2
```

First of all this modification is written to Transaction log buffer..SQLServer then writes this modification to disk, before we get successfull commit..This is called write Ahead logging and this type of commits will not be periodic or any thing..This happens per statement

> And in where the dirty pages are stored in the SQL server when the memory is not big enough to hold the data in the buffer pool(in temp db or in the respective databases)? and for how long the uncommitted data is preserved in SQL server and where?

consider the same update transaction and this update needs to touch three pages..and one page is not in buffer pool..In this case,SQL reads the page from disk and places it in buffer pool and modifies it..Now this page is called dirty page...

These type of pages will be flushed to disk  ,When check point occurs..check point occurs due to various conditions as mentioned in below link

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189573.aspx

Comment: check point will flush everything,either committed or not committed ,since this transactions are written to log file..SQLServer will read from that ,in worst case scenario